# iphone App : How to remove toolbar from navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2

In my app first time I have taken navigation controller toolbar. After faced some problems i remove toolbar and then i took navigation controller navigationbar.

Now my problem is when I run my app navigation controller toolbar show in the bottom part of screen. when i hide toolbar then botton controls functionality doesnt work.

Please guide me.

Suggest me the way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly it means by navigation controller toolbar. Is it a navigation controller having toolbar? Also, what is navigation controller tabbar. Is it a navigation controller inside tabBarController? Have you added toolbar on rootViewController of navigationController? It will be helpful if you can provide your controller and view hierarchy.

Comment: I have one view controller and in that i have added navigation controller and in navigation controller i have added navigation bar buttons.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot could also help us better understand your problem

Comment: As I understand your problem is. You have a NavigationController with navigationBar. You have added a toolbar at bottom of it. Now when you hide the toolbar the button controls on toolbar does not respond. Am I correct? Now what you want to remove toolbar? Is there some specific condition that you need toolbar for some cases and not in others? If you dont need the toolbar can't you remove it from navigationController view? How is it added on navigationController programactically or using Interface builder.

Comment: give some code so that we can understand your problem properly..!!

Answer (score 4):

self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=YES;

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

For more information, Visit [UINavigationItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Again edited your answer to add developer documentation just as this was appearing in low quality posts.